# Does running full node in prune mode contribute to BTC network?

Tags: full-node, pruning, relay

If I run current (v22.0.0) full node in prune mode will it contribute to the BTC network (better security, etc..)?
In v11.x.x the relay was not working hence no contribution to the network at all (if I am right...).
(I don't need to run the full node (wallet included) for myself, I just want to contribute to the BTC system itself.)
Thanks!

Comment: If contributing is what you're after, make sure your network configuration allows inbound connections to your node: https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#network-configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pruned nodes still contribute to the network. They still receive, send, and validate all blocks and transactions on the network. This by itself is beneficial to the network. Additionally, pruned nodes will have the most recent blocks (by default, at least 1 days worth) so they can also serve those blocks.